# How to throttle upload without affecting download speed?

Tags: networking

By throttling upload speed with (IPtables,TC, qdisq) my download speed gets proportionally throttled as well. For example I should be able to throttle my upload speed to say 200kbit and have download speed of 3mbit but that's not the case, the down speed drops to a similar range as well. What is the reason behind that? and is there a way to achieve such un-proportional throttling ?

P.s. the drop in download speed is not related to wrong configurations of TC or iptables or network, it seems like a network protocol definition

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you can use U32 to match a flow to a source or destination IP. So you would create your tc class, and then match the local IP as source or destination and assign the flow (classid of tc)

> $TC qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 30
>
> $TC class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 50mbit
>
> $TC class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:2 htb rate 10mbit
>
> $U32 match ip dst 1.1.1.1/32 flowid 1:1
>
> $U32 match ip src 1.1.1.1/32 flowid 1:2

[u32 usage](https://www.linux.org/docs/man8/tc-u32.html)

[tc Usage](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/advanced_traffic_control)

[Example](https://help.atmail.com/hc/en-us/articles/201566464-Throttling-Bandwidth-using-Traffic-Controller-for-Linux)